# Pdf generation xhtml2pdf pisa

Tags: python, xhtml

Pdf exception in `xhtmlpdf`.

I'm trying generate invoice pdf using `xhtml,` `pisa`, when I'm trying to covert html table to pdf it raise an error.

```
spanning problem in <PmlTable@0x7FB134B5BDC0 2 rows x 13 cols(tallest row 23)> with cell(0,0) containing
'<PmlKeepInFrame at 0x7fb134bba040> size= maxWidth=39.57692x maxHeight=268435448' hmax=2 lim=2 avail=612.0 x 268435455
H0=[None, None] H=[23.437499000000003, 23.437499000000003]
spanCons={(0, 1): 31.874999, (0, 7): 23.437499000000003} list index out of range
```

How can I fix this

Comment: More context is needed. Add a minimal version of your code so we can help you diagnose the cause.